# VLOOKUP formula between two different spreadsheets - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to use VLOOKUP function between two different sheets in two different spreadsheets.
In the "range" parameter of VLOOKUP I have inserted a range via IMPORTRANGE(different_spreadsheet_url, range_string) and I got null value, although the value that I search for is appear in the input range.

I think there is some problem with using IMPORTRANGE inside VLOOKUP but I can't figure it out.

I would be happy if anyone can help me with this or suggest another way to solve my issue.

Thanks.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz of course.
Here it's spreadsheet number 1 that I search in:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nGI6-Vwv_zX-0DfN8zFwVYJTd00iXY3HLcSlU_rjhEo/edit?usp=sharing

And here I using VLOOKUP (B1 cell), spreadsheet number 2:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nzNMR2TDFzO8K8TxG5t9Jv1CHFrthoHKXzvnaTZCrsw/edit?usp=sharing

Both spreadsheets have permission to access one to each other.

Thanks for your helping.

Comment: Thanks. I would go ahead and edit those into your question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have quite the unusual problem for the following reasons:

1. You want to use a `VLOOKUP`, but select a column to the left, which `VLOOKUP` doesn't like.
2. You can't use the usual `INDEX`-`MATCH` workaround because you want to use an `ArrayFormula`, which works with `VLOOKUP`, but not `INDEX`.

So what we need to do is swap the columns from your source sheet before using `VLOOKUP`. We can achieve this with a `QUERY` and `select` the Columns in reverse, like so:

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(FILTER(A:A,A:A),Query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nGI6-Vwv_zX-0DfN8zFwVYJTd00iXY3HLcSlU_rjhEo/edit#gid=0","example1!A:B"),"select Col2,Col1"),2,0))
```

Or more readably:

```
=ArrayFormula(
    VLOOKUP(
        FILTER(A:A,A:A),
        Query(
            IMPORTRANGE(
                "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nGI6-Vwv_zX-0DfN8zFwVYJTd00iXY3HLcSlU_rjhEo/edit#gid=0",
                "example1!A:B"
            ),
            "select Col2,Col1"
        ),
        2,
        0
    )
)
```

I also went ahead and used all non-blanks of column A using `FILTER` as well, so you can expand your data if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much.
About using FILTER - It's a good idea but its shrink the output array.
If I want to keep the gap between cells but remove null values how can I do that?
I have added an example to cell A7 in spreadsheet no.2.
Thanks again!

Comment: @vector_y Then 1. Just use `A:A` instead of `FILTER(A:A,A:A)`, then 2. Put the entire `VLOOKUP` in an `IFNA`.